# Flutter: what can I put in setState() method?

Tags: flutter, dart

is there a meaningful difference between these?

```
setState(() {
  _registerIndex++;
});
_registerScrollController.jumpTo(0);
```

and

```
setState(() {
  _registerIndex++;
  _registerScrollController.jumpTo(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, as long as none of them awaits for a `Future`.

However, if you don't need to update the counter value in your UI, you also don't need `setState` in this case, because `ScrollController.jumpTo()` will do the job internally.